# The root certificate of the signature in the app package or bundle must be trusted

Tags: xamarin, uwp, windows, xamarin.uwp

I am working on mobile application development for which I am using Xamarin with Visual studio 2017.
I have created a package for UWP(Universal Windows Platform) platform for windows mobile app, which I tested on my local machine by installing it which is working fine.
However, when I have given this entire package(appxbundle etc.) to other user for testing, on there machine it is giving the following error while installing.

> Error 0x800B0109 :The root certificate of the signature in the app package or bundle must be trusted.

SO what is the reason the same package works on one machine and not on the other ?
Any help on this appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works on your device because you have already run it via debugger so the app certificate is already installed.

To make it work on someone else's device you either need to install via Powershell, which handles the certficate installation (right-click the `ps1` file which comes along with the package and `Run with Powershell`) or you first have to install the certifiate manually by double-clicking the certificate file in the `_Test` folder.

Comment: Ok, Can we install the package without certificate ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. The certficiate needs to be installed before the application is sideloaded

Comment: Is there any difference/problem if we try to install the package with .appxbundle OR with .ps1 ?

Comment: The `ps1` solution is a bit less user friendly, but automatically installs the certficate as well. Once you install the certificate, you can normally double-click the bundle next time and it will work without additional steps.

Comment: OK got it ! However in my case the user is business user so they dont know anything about certifcate etc. So how can we sideload this ?

Comment: You should give them the instructions of how to install the certificate. It is necessary, because the system checks the package identity against the certificate so that it can be trusted. See sideloading info here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps#sideload-your-app-package

Comment: instead of sideloading can we include certificate in appxbundle. so it will get automatically installed

Comment: I think it still has to be installed manually, because the PC needs to trust it, before it will install the `appxbundle`...

Comment: Nope we don't want to do it manually. As all the users will not having admin access to the system. So i am looking to include in appxbundle itself

Comment: @MartinZikmund so when we download an from windows store, then how it works without installing any certificate manually.

Comment: @AbhishekMaurya I think that in such a case the certificate is provided by Microsoft, so it is already trusted.